# How to set liquibase variables in application.yml in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, docker-compose, liquibase

When Spring Boot application first starts, the liquibase should create a user for runtime usage. The password should be configurable, so that it could vary across environments. I am trying to achieve that like this:

```xml
    <changeSet id="2021-12-02 12:00:01" author="author" dbms="mysql">
        <sql>
            CREATE USER consumer_app IDENTIFIED BY '${spring.datasource.password}';
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            DROP USER IF EXISTS consumer_app;
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

and application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    user: root
    password: root
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
    username: consumer_app
    password: password
```

And it does not work. The password is set as `${spring.datasource.password}`, not as the value of this property in application.yml. Without single quotes I get a syntax error.

The project is built with Maven.

The password is going to be injected from docker-compose, so having init.sql with docker-managed variables is also an option.

Comment: can you try without the single quotes? https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-property-substitution.html

Comment: @hovanessyan, without single quotes I get a syntax error

Comment: looking at the doc it says in the SQL example: "Currently, changelog property substitution is not available in SQL format."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spring boot you are passing parameters from yaml with following example:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      spring.datasource.password: ${spring.datasource.password}
```

note that only parameters passed to `spring.liquibase.parameters` are being send to liquibase context.

Comment: It helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use insert  into mysql.user instead, and use insert liquiabse balise instead of plain SQL to pass param on value.